# Generating models from database views in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Am trying to generate models from database views with the sole purpose of viewing and searching complex records from various tables.

However I get "Table 'XXX' does not exist".Logically views are like tables.

Any creative workarounds?

Comment: As far as i know, database views are not supported in yii. Is'n it anymore? ...but maybe this changed at an new yii version!?

Comment: @ the bndr: I'm looking at an AR class generated by gii off a database view.  They are just treated like tables that you can only select.

Answer (score 3):

I created a AR model of a view using [gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii) a few days ago.  I just had to put in the view name and it worked.  You must be typing the view name wrong.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782879/calling-a-database-view-in-yii-using-active-record) is the SO question I asked about it a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

That is a system-specific database access violation, and does not relate to the Yii code at least, have your webhost equip your MySQL username with SHOW VIEW privileges for the database.