# How to use this SQL in CDbCriteria

Tags: php, sql, yii

I've currently got this SQL

```
 SELECT


       MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 1 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 2 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 3 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 4 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 5 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 6 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question6

       FROM tbl_event_attendees AS ea

       LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u ON ea.user_id = u.id
       LEFT JOIN tbl_event AS e ON ea.event_id = e.id                  
       LEFT JOIN tbl_user_variables AS uv on u.id = uv.user_id

       GROUP BY ea.id
```

And I need to put it into my existing CDbCriteria + extend the relations. I need each Question 1 to 6 to be a variable I can use to put inside a cgridview but I'm struggling to get it working. If I use CSQLdataprovider it works fine BUT I need the existing criteria I already have.

My current criteria

```
  public function search() {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id, true);
        $criteria->compare('event_id', $this->event_id, true);
        $criteria->compare('status_id', $this->status_id, true);
        $criteria->compare('checkin_status_id', $this->checkin_status_id, true);
//        $criteria->compare('guest_invites', $this->guest_invites, true);
        $criteria->compare('guest_of_user_id', $this->guest_of_user_id, true);
        $criteria->compare('user_id', $this->user_id, true);
        $criteria->compare('assign_group', $this->assign_group, true);

//        $criteria->with = 'eventAttendeesGroup';
        $criteria->with = 'user';
        $criteria->compare('user.forename', $this->user_forename, true);
        $criteria->compare('user.surname', $this->user_surname, true);
        $criteria->compare('user.company', $this->user_company, true);
        $criteria->compare('user.telephone', $this->user_telephone, true);
        $criteria->compare('user.dob', $this->user_dateofbirth, true);

        //need to get rid of this
        $criteria->compare('userVariables.value', $this->userType_value, true);

        $criteria->order = 'user.surname ASC';

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            //manages the pagination and how many users appear on the onsite reg page 
            'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>50),
            //'pagination'=>false,
        ));
    }
```

Anyone got any ideas?

I presume I'd have to set variables for each question and add them to a relation like usertype.variable and $this->variable but at a total loss.

edit.

I can get

```
     function newsearch(){
     $rawData=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT


                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 1 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question1,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 2 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question2,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 3 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question3,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 4 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question4,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 5 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question5,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 6 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question6

                    FROM tbl_event_attendees AS ea

                    LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u ON ea.user_id = u.id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_event AS e ON ea.event_id = e.id                  
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_user_variables AS uv on u.id = uv.user_id

                    GROUP BY ea.id')->queryAll();
// or using: $rawData=User::model()->findAll();
return  $dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
    'id'=>'Questions',
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
             'Question1', 'Question2', 'Question3',
        ),
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
));
```

To display the sql in the grid, but I still can't access my model data alongside this.

Comment: Do you really want to use CDbCriteria, it's possible to implement it but it might be easier to use CDbCommand and write a custom query, and use the CArrayDataProvider

Comment: Because this is a project I've inherited there is too much dependencies on this functionality being the same. I thought about adding and joining two data providers as an array together but I could not get the result I wanted as the sql data and data from the model did not link up at all when using the search / export which is the end game this bit of data.

Comment: Ok i have added an answer let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I've added the sql to a cArraydataprovider with the sql working correctly, do you know of any resources of adding model data as well to the array so I know how to do it properly next time?

Comment: So you want to add the entire model to the result set of the query? you can add anything to an array if you wan't this won't be a problem for the CArrayprovider if that is what you mean

Comment: I want to be able to use my current set of data (what is currently in my search) and each question. Each question and variable will be a header in my gridview. I can get them working seperately but as soon as I try to use them together I get no luck. I have the SQL working as a cdataarray, is it posible to just add my entire search function to this?

Comment: To archive this take a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/232/using-filters-with-cgridview-and-carraydataprovider/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107221/discussion-between-tim-van-der-gaag-and-alex).

Comment: @Alex every time I did these kind of things I've put $criteria->with(..) before $criteria->compare(..) ... I don't think this is your problem but it's worth a shot... Also please try to dump the criteria at the end before execution and go through it... it's not possible that it works in sql but not with CDbCriteria especially if relations are set.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it thoroughly. But you will need to add the attributes to the model class and add the query select statement to the CDbCriteria ([select](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#select-detail)) attribute an use the [together](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#together-detail) attribute so that the query is preformed at once.

i'll assume this is the tbl_event_attendees model, when used correctly Yii will populate the records automaticly

```
class tblEventAttendees  extends CActiveRecord { 

public $Question1;
public $Question2;
public $Question3;
public $Question4;
public $Question5;
public $Question6;

...


    public function search() {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = [
            't.*',
            'user.*',
            'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 1 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question1',
            'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 2 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question2',
            'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 3 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question3',
            'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 4 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question4',
            'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 5 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question5',
            'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 6 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question6',
            // add what you need
        ];

        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id, true);
        $criteria->compare('event_id', $this->event_id, true);
        $criteria->compare('status_id', $this->status_id, true);
        $criteria->compare('checkin_status_id', $this->checkin_status_id, true);
//        $criteria->compare('guest_invites', $this->guest_invites, true);
        $criteria->compare('guest_of_user_id', $this->guest_of_user_id, true);
        $criteria->compare('user_id', $this->user_id, true);
        $criteria->compare('assign_group', $this->assign_group, true);

//        $criteria->with = 'eventAttendeesGroup';
        $criteria->compare('user.forename', $this->user_forename, true);
        $criteria->compare('user.surname', $this->user_surname, true);
        $criteria->compare('user.company', $this->user_company, true);
        $criteria->compare('user.telephone', $this->user_telephone, true);
        $criteria->compare('user.dob', $this->user_dateofbirth, true);

        //need to get rid of this
        $criteria->compare('userVariables.value', $this->userType_value, true);

        $criteria->order = 'user.surname ASC';

        $criteria->with = array('user','event','userVariables');
        $criteria->together = true;

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            //manages the pagination and how many users appear on the onsite reg page
            'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>50),
            //'pagination'=>false,
        ));
    }
```

**UPDATE**

After some testing we found out the problem was not in the query, but in the usage of aliases. Yii maps the results of the query using the aliases and the alias is extracted from the query using a preg_match function see https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.17/framework/db/ar/CActiveFinder.php#L954

So changing this

```
$criteria->select = [
    't.*',
    'user.*',
    'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 1 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question1',
    'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 2 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question2',
    'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 3 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question3',
    'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 4 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question4',
    'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 5 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question5',
    'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 6 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question6',
    // add what you need
];
```

To this solved the problem

```
$criteria->select = [
    't.*',
    'user.*',
    'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 1 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question1',
    'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 2 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question2',
    'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 3 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question3',
    'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 4 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question4',
    'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 5 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question5',
    'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 6 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question6',
    // add what you need
];
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't get this to work. It's still looking at the eventattendees table no matter what I tell it to look at, as the uv. looks as the usertypevariable questions. I've added all the relations I need and it's still saying it can't find the column. I've added a sort of working cdatarrayprovider to my OP but I still can' access the model data.

Comment: Active record "EventAttendees" is trying to select an invalid column "MAX(CASE WHEN userTypeVariables.user_type_variables_id = 1 THEN userTypeVariables.value ELSE NULL END) Question1". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.

But it's recognising the relation so I don't understand why it can't find the column

Comment: hmm ok, Enable CWebLogRoute to see the query that are executed so you can troubleshoot this, check whether $criteria->together = true; is set correctly if this attribute is not set Yii will use lazy loading for accessing relations.

Comment: Yep, relations all fine and all together. Looks like the functionality will just have to be abandoned. Not sure why the framework makes it so difficult to just use two dataproviders in the first place!

Comment: Yep , the SQL finishes in THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) Question6 FROM `tbl_event_attendees`  , seems to be completely ignoring wher eit should be coming fom. the uv questions are from user_variable table.

Comment: can you come to the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107221/discussion-between-tim-van-der-gaag-and-alex

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a [MYSQL database view](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) and use it in a Yii model. With this approach you can use all Yii model features like any other table based model (except `INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE` operations) keeping existing features from your original query and criteria's:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myviewname AS 
... your SQL ...
```

After `MYSQL database view` creation, [make sure to create Yii model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782879/calling-a-database-view-in-yii-using-active-record) for your database view. In this model use your existing custom `search()`. Finally use it in your programs as you want, for example in CGridView, reports, etc.